# Show/Hide a div on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i'm writing a small script to show/hide a div when other div is clicked, but I can't get the second div clickable.

Here's my code so far:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('div#ordontia').click(function(){
        $(this).next('div#ordontia2').slideToggle("slow");
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/65AK2/1/

Every time a "button" is clicked a new div with a description should appear on the bottom of the table. (the blue div on the bottom). If another button is clicked then the previous description should close and another one should open in the same place. (not implement yet)

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Where is your `#ordontia2` div in the fiddle?

Comment: @ComFreek It's at the bottom.

Comment: @biip: Do you want to have this for every button? Then you should work with your `botaomedicina` class. See my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why do you want to select your element with next if it has an unique ID?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('div#ordontia').click(function(){
        $('div#ordontia2').slideToggle("slow");
    });
});
```

more general if you add more divs:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.botaomedicina').click(function(){
        $('#'+$(this).attr('id')+'2').slideToggle("slow");
    });
});
```

with all others closing:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.botaomedicina').click(function(){
        $('.botaomedicinadescription').slideUp("slow");
        $('#'+$(this).attr('id')+'2').slideToggle("slow");
    });
});
```

Comment: thanks, the second one is almost exactly what i want! i just need to make sure the div closes before the new one opens. maybe something like this? $('.descricaomedicina').slideToggle(0);before the first line of function()?

Answer (score 2):

Don't use `$.next`, it only selects siblings of the current element:

> Get the immediately following sibling of each element in the set of
>   matched elements. If a selector is provided, it retrieves the next
>   sibling only if it matches that selector.
>   — [jQuery documentation: .next()](http://api.jquery.com/next/)

Use the normal one:

```
$('div#ordontia2').slideToggle("slow");
```

Answer (score 2):

Fixed it.

```
http://jsfiddle.net/65AK2/2/
```

firstly, it lookx like your toggled div was mal-formed.  I didnt see a  for it.

Secondly, if you know what the ID of the other div is, you dont need to say:

```
$(this).next("#item");
```

, it would make no sense.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('div#ordontia').click(function(){
        $('div#ordontia2').slideToggle("slow");
    });
});
```

remove `this` ;)

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('div#ordontia').click(function(){
        $('div#ordontia2').slideToggle("slow");
    });
});
```

updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/65AK2/4/

Answer (score 0):

You can do it directly by an **ID selector**

http://jsfiddle.net/65AK2/3/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#ordontia').click(function(){
        $('#ordontia2').slideToggle("slow");
    });
});
```