# Show / Hide HTML using swatch / HTML 5 - dynamic HTML

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a swatch CSS implemented in my template.

```
<div data-option-index="0" class="swatch color clearfix">

    <div class="swatch-element  available" data-value="ONE">
        <input type="radio" checked="checked" value="ONE" name="CheckPurity" id="swatch-1-ONE">
        <label for="swatch-1-ONE">ONE <img alt="" src="./assets/images/soldout.png" class="crossed-out"></label>
    </div>

     <div class="swatch-element  available" data-value="TWO">
            <input type="radio" checked="checked" value="TWO" name="CheckPurity" id="swatch-1-TWO">
                <label for="swatch-1-TWO">TWO <img alt="" src="./assets/images/soldout.png" class="crossed-out">
                </label>
         </div>
</div>
```

[image]

So when user click on Button "ONE" it get Selected and "TWO" De-Selected and vice versa

Everything is fine at this point.

But now I want to show / Hide table on base of the button selected
Let say if One is selected that I want to show table with Id = "TblSpec_ONE" and hide all other tables and vice versa

. HTML code for the same is:

```
<div class="description"> 
    <table id="TblSpec_ONE" class="MGC-TblDtl">
        <tbody>
         <tr>
           <td>VALUE of Button </td>
            <td>ONE</td>
         </tr>
         </tbody>
     </table>

<table id="TblSpec_TWO" class="MGC-TblDtl">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
     <td>VALUE of Button </td>
     <td>TWO</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Now my problem is that how I can manage the same as my HTML (number of Button & respective table ) is dynamic.

So kindly guide me How I can achieve the same.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Show/Hide a div on click](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19641409/show-hide-a-div-on-click)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extend the code that you already have for the swatch, and add some logic to control what `table` should be displayed. It should be easy as both have the same `class` and a different `id` that can be used to link it to the active button. The steps would be:

1. Hide all the tables that have the class `MGC-TblDtl`.

   ```
   $("table.MGC-TblDtl").hide();
   ```
2. Get the `data-value` for the active state of the swatch and show only the table that has the id `"TblSpec_" + data-value`. Note that this code will differ depending on how you have implemented the function to process the swatch, but it could be something like this:

   ```
   $("TblSpec_" + $(this).data("value")).show();
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, Alvaro Montoro on the base of his answer here is how code go. for any other future reference

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $("table.MGC-TblDtl").hide();

        $("table.MGC-TblDtl:last").show(); // show the last element as TWO is selected

        $(".swatch-element").click(function () {

            $("table.MGC-TblDtl").hide();
            $("#TblSpec_" + $(this).data("value")).show();
        });

    });
</script>
```